# WebGL texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I am trying to set up a cube texture for reflection, but I got this error:

```
  WebGL: drawElements: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. 
It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'.
 Or the texture is Float or Half Float type with linear filtering while OES_float_linear or OES_half_float_linear extension is not enabled.
index.js:404 WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.
```

I am sure the images (PNG) have been loaded correctly, since console.log prints the correct power of two height and width...

I got this error when I trying to draw anything, even in another shader program..

Here is the code for texture loading:

```
gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
cubeMap = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubeMap);

gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, 0, gl.RGBA,
gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_pos_x);
//5 more times for different faces of the cube

gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 );
gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "texture"),0);
```

Comment: Show texture loading code please.

Comment: I had these kinds of problems when I started also, all I can say is, start from simplest examples, like "hello triangle" here: https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/books/openglr_es_20_programming_guide_sample.pdf then 'bisect' the differences between your code and the examples until you find the problem.

Comment: Pay special attention also to texture filtering, and "ST_clamp" etc. modes. Make sure you read all the docs and configure it similarly to a working example before trying to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add these in

```
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I put:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);  
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

in between my activeTexture and bindTexture calls and it worked for me.